# C# 'is' operator Clarification

Tags: c#

Does the `is` operator indicate whether or not an object **is an instance** of a certain class, or only if **it can be casted** to that class?

Assume I have a `DbCommand` called `command` that has actually has been initialized as a `SqlCommand`.  What is the result of `command is OracleCommand`?

(`SqlCommand` and `OracleCommand` both inherit from `DbCommand`)

Comment: Wouldn't the result be false, because neither DbCommand nor SqlCommand are instances of OracleCommand?

Comment: `is` indicates if an object is an instance of or derived from the type. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: @they: Aren't those two definitions the same?

Comment: This is one of those things you could have tested in the time it took to write the question. :P

Comment: @theycallmorty: How are they different? `obj` is an instance of `Class` if and only if it can be casted to `Class`, right? Unless I'm missing something...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It checks if the object is a member of that type, or a type that inherits from or implements the base type or interface. In a way, it does check if the object can be cast to said type.

`command is OracleCommand` returns false as it's an `SqlCommand`, not an `OracleCommand`. However, both `command is SqlCommand` and `command is DbCommand` will return true as it is a member of both of those types and can therefore be downcast or upcast to either respectively.

If you have three levels of inheritance, e.g. `BaseClass`, `SubClass` and `SubSubClass`, an object initialized as `new SubClass()` only returns true for `is BaseClass` and `is SubClass`. Although `SubSubClass` derives from both of these, the object itself is not an instance of it, so `is SubSubClass` returns false.

Answer (score 6):

> An `is` expression evaluates to true if the provided expression is non-null, and the provided object *can be cast* to the provided type without causing an exception to be thrown.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> An is expression evaluates to true if [...] *expression* can be cast to type

Answer (score 3):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

> An is expression evaluates to true if the provided expression is non-null, and the provided object **can be cast** to the provided type without causing an exception to be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

`is` indicate if the object can be casted to a class or interface.

If you have a BaseClass and a SubClass then:

```
var obj = new SubClass();
```

`obj is SubClass` returns true;

`obj is BaseClass` also returns true;

Comment: If you want to compare to the actual type, use `command.GetType().Equals(typeof(SqlCommand))`.

Comment: What about unrelated types with an explicit cast operator to convert between them?

Answer (score 0):

**if(something is X)** checks if the underlying type of **something** is **X**. This is significantly different from checking if a type supports casting to **X** since many types can support casts to **X** without being of type **X**.

Conversely the **as** operator attempts a conversion to a particular type and assigns **null** if source type is not within the inheritance chain of the target type.